# Check if Key has Key in Firebase - JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime DB structured like this:

```
users
    userid1
        name: "name1"
        email: "email1"
        specialValue: "special"
    userid2
        name: "name2"
        email: "email2"
```

I want to check if a user(I already have a userid) has the `specialValue` key. So this should return true for userid1, and false for userid2.

I have tried this:

```
var check = firebase.database().ref('users').orderByKey().equalTo(userid).once("value", function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log("key exists");
    } else {
        console.log("key doesn't exist");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a query for a node if you know the key, so this should work (and be a bit faster once you have a lot of nodes):

```
firebase.database().ref('users').child(userid).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        console.log("exists");
    } else {
        console.log("doesn't exist");
    }
});
```

In addition to being shorter and faster, this also is guaranteed to give just one snapshot as a result, where a query may have multiple results. Even though your query will only match one result, the API still returns the one result as a list and you'd have to loop over that with `forEach`.

Comment: What I was doing is creating a user and then adding the name and email. I then check if it has the specialValue (if its a new user it wont), and assign a default value if it doesn't or use the value if it does.